# Excel SQL query parameter behaviour

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I've created a spreadsheet that simply allows the user to enter a parameter in a cell and a list is shown as a table based on a SQL query with a the parameter.

I have a stored procedure that does a basic select query and has a variable that is set in the where clause like this (I want to be able to do wildcard lookups)...

```
where @FileID like Data_fileID
```

I then pass the parameter to the variable by setting the SQL Command text on a button click in VBA...

```
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("FileID_LU").OLEDBConnection
    .CommandText = "EXEC SP_DB_FileLU '" & Range("FileID").Value & "'"
End With
Sheet1.Range("UpdateMsg").Value = "Getting data..."
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("FileID_LU").Refresh
Sheet1.Range("UpdateMsg").Value = "Here you go..."
End Sub
```

So the user enters a file ID into a cell that I've named `FileID`, hits the update button, the connection properties command text box is updated with a new query and then the connection is refreshed.

This seems to work fine with individual file IDs that are definitely in the database, but if I enter `5%` and hit the update button, I get a list of everything beginning with `5`, but the query doesn't update after any subsequent updates with different parameters.

If I go to the connection properties, the last query (after the `5%`)is displayed in the text box, but it hasn't refreshed - if I click refresh the table by right clicking and selecting refresh, I get the results of the last query, but not with the button click.
My message cell reads 'Here you go...' but the data connection hasn't refreshed.

Why wont it refresh after a wildcard lookup?